# Radio button to select gender. How can I successfully retrieve the selected gender?

Tags: mysql, tkinter, sql-insert

The following code is a function to retrieve the input and store the record to a table in mysql

```py
def addrecord():
    cstmid = tcstmid.get("1.0")  # retrieve input
    cstmpass = tcstmpass.get("1.0")
    cstname = tcstname.get("1.0")
    cstmdob = tcstmdob.get("1.0")
    cstmsex = v.get()
    cstmaddress = tcstmaddress.get("1.0")

#DATABASE CONNECTION
conn=sqltor.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="iwakiri",database="APPARELSTORE")
tkcursor=conn.cursor(prepared=True)
query=("Insert into customer(cstmid,cstmpass,cstmname,cstmdob,cstmsex,cstmaddress) values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')")
tkcursor.execute(query)
conn.commit()
tkcursor.close()
```

The following code is for making radio buttons with options to select gender

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("325x400")
root.title("Apparel store")

# Gender Label
lcstmsex = tk.Label(root, font=('helvetica', 10), text='Select Gender:')
lcstmsex.grid(row=9, column=1)

# Radio Button
v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(0)

# Radio Button for Gender
r1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Female', value=1, variable=v)
r1.grid(row=10, column=1)

r2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Male', value=2, variable=v)
r2.grid(row=11, column=1)

r3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Other', value=3, variable=v)
r3.grid(row=12, column=1)
```

**ERROR:**

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cstmsex' in 'field list'

**QUESTION:**

What am I doing wrong with the code for the radio button and how can I fix it so that I can enter records into tkinter gui and store them in a table in MySQL?

Comment: It seems like your error are not coming from the tkinter application, but rather from the fact that `mysql` cannot find any column called `cstmsex`, perhaps you should verify the table column names in your database, maybe there is a spelling error?

Comment: Just noticed something, why are you not passing in any values to the placeholders in your query? The querying is probably done wrong, your passing in variables into the string?

Comment: The title of the question and the body of the question ask two completely different things. The title asks about getting the value from a radiobutton, but the body is asking about a mysql error.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Insert into customer(cstmid,cstmpass,cstmname,cstmdob,cstmsex,cstmaddress) values ...
```

is not a valid `INSERT` statement.

Right after the table's name, inside the parentheses you must enumerate all the columns that will receive the values that you supply.
What you are doing though, is passing the variables where you saved the values of the columns.

So change the statement to this:

```
query = "Insert into customer(id, pass, name, dob, sex, address) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
tkcursor.execute(query, (cstmid, cstmpass, cstmname, cstmdob, cstmsex, cstmaddress,))
```

I use `?` placeholders for the column values which are passed in the method `execute()` as a tuple.

Change the names of the columns to the actual ones.

Comment: I tried your code and received an error: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'   How do I fix this? and why are we allowed to use column name that does not exist like *customer(id, pass, name, dob, sex, address)* ?

Comment: @Iappreciateyourhelp In my answer I mention: "Change the names of the columns to the actual ones"

Comment: for entering date, what do we use instead of *?*  at *cstmid, cstmpass, cstmname, cstmdob, cstmsex, cstmaddress* I used your code and got an error: *Incorrect date value: '2' for column 'CSTMDOB' at row 1*

Comment: If the column's data type is DATE you must pass a string value in the format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I entered a date *2020-11-19*  in tkinter and it returned the said error. Is there any change that I should make in *"Insert into customer(cstmid, cstmpass, cstmname, cstmdob, cstmsex, cstmaddress) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"*

Comment: I already said that you should use the column names. Are `cstmid, cstmpass, cstmname, cstmdob, cstmsex, cstmaddress` column names? If they are then the code should work if the date is stored in the variable `cstmdob` like `cstmdob = "2020-11-19"`.